# What is the base and dim for the kernel of this linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Ok, so i have a linear transformation that is from second degree polynomial to a $2\times 2$ matrix

$$T : \mathbf{P_{2}[X]} \to \mathbb{R^{2x2}}$$

which defined as:

$$T(P(X)) = \begin{pmatrix} P(1) & P(0) \\ P(-1) & P(0) \end{pmatrix}$$

I have been asked to find the dim and the base for the kernel of $T$.

So after I calculated it, it turned out that $\ker(T) = 0$. and therefore there is not a base for it.
what I did was:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a+b+c & a \\ a-b+c & a \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

so I got:

$a=0, b=c, b = -c \implies b=c=0=a$

I wanted to know if I was right...
and if not, I will be more than happy to know my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks correct.
Also you can notice that a second degree polinomial can only have two roots.
The kernel here requires the polinomial to have three roots, and that is impossible unless the polinomial equals zero for all the values of x.